# Wall socket not working after changing lighting connection

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, socket

I am having a problem in my apartment after making changes to the lighting switches. I live in Germany and live in my own apartment.

We had one multi-way switch and one normal switch which controls the lighting in our the apartment. In order to install our kitchen we had to close the switch box permanently. Before closing the switch box we made the multi-way switch and the normal switch permanently on. Now the light which was controlled by a multi-way switch has only one switch and the other one is always ON which could be useful for smart lights.

After the changes were done some of the wall sockets and the balcony light and balcony wall sockets aren’t working in my apartment. I got this done by an electrician since I was not comfortable in making the changes. I am not sure if the problem is due to this change or if it was coincidental. I don’t know how to find the root cause and get the sockets working again.

The switch box has been permanently closed and there is no access to it. A wooden plank has been installed on the wall.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: A proper electrician would never bury a switch box in the wall. It's against code, dangerous and, as you found out, difficult to diagnose and fix issues. You need to regain access to that box.

Comment: Where are you? From what I've seen here, in some places "permanently closed ... no access" could be against the rules. Also, have you asked the electrician to check thrir work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that a hot wire passing through the switch box was supplying the outlets and was mishandled. I'd start by trying to determine whether those outlets are on the same breaker as the lights controlled by the original switch. If you can verify that they are, it's a strong indication that the problem is related to the recent work.

Then, whether you can verify that or not, invite the electrician back to investigate. They're ultimately responsible if they caused the problem, and if they didn't they're still much better qualified to find the cause than we are, with what little we know about your wiring.